# Chrome Browser GCM - TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS - How to unregister/clear all registered app ids (registration.pushManager.subscribe)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm developing a service worker and push notifications for one of my projects. 
I did a mistake and as a result I registered in my browser more than 2k apps.

On the page `chrome://gcm-internals` I see 2450 similar records:

**Registered App Ids:**

```
com.google.android.gms,com.google.chrome.invalidations,...,
...
wp:http://localhost:9001/#0027E3C3-0257-42DD-8B34-4F2F6AA90-V2,
wp:http://localhost:9001/#004F20F2-BD18-4010-9057-7D9942BB1-V2,
wp:http://localhost:9001/#005821E7-DB83-4354-B7D5-A22AF0D96-V2,
wp:http://localhost:9001/#0071000C-BF28-4D70-9330-C9DE4CB1A-V2,
...
```

After I did that mistake I'm getting an error when I'm trying to subscribe to push messages:

```
const subscribeOptions = {
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(vapid_key)
};

registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions).then(...)
```

**Error:**

```
code: 20  
message: Registration failed - push service error  
name: AbortError
```

**Registration Log:**

*App Id:* wp:http://localhost:9001/#7C6FBD76-0ADA-4934-A32B-8D61FE880-V2
*Event:*    Registration response received
*Details:* **TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS**

Is it possible to unregister/clear all these app ids?

Comment: From this [thread in github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/584), you can check the solution offered by the community.
To have an idea about **TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS** error, you can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529977/firebase-token-error-too-many-registrations?rq=1).

Comment: @jess thanks for the links, but looks like it isn't my case because I don't have an "unsubscribe" action in my browser for all those registered app ids

Comment: Is that so, sorry I'm not able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same issue on Chrome testing push notification and my solution was to remove log file within GCM Store folder

C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\GCM Store

[log_google_chrome_gcm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEnbd.png)

Comment: Yes, your solution helped me as well. Thanks