# How to reproduce TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I am seeing this crash in FirebaseCrashlytics console for my Android app on PlayStore.

My app is Cordova based and uses https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm Plugin for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Here is the crash logs from Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard.

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: 
TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS
com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPlugin$1.onComplete

Caused by java.io.IOException
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS

Caused by java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:9)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$3$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(:4)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

### Culprit devices

My app is crashing for Pixel 2 XL, Galaxy S20 FE 5G, ELS-NX9

### What I have tried?

I have tried with Pixel 2 XL emulator but I do not see the crash.

#### I have 3 questions?

- What is the root cause of this issue?
- How to reproduce this on Emulator?
- How to fix this issue?

### Related thread I found on Stackoverflow

Also I have seen a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529977/firebase-token-error-too-many-registrations) but it does not answer my question. According to one of the answers there, the crash is more likely to occur when the app is run on Firebase Test Lab. But in my case these crashes are happening with real users not with Robots(Test Lab).

Comment: Have you found any solution? We are facing the same issue.

Comment: I could not find the exact root cause. But Adding an Exception handling code (try, catch block) stopped my app from crashing.